# Binance get_historical_klines end_str is not working

Tags: python, api, binance, binance-api-client

I am trying to get the data from 1th Dec. 2017 to 1st Jan 2018, the output when checked for *len(historical_data)* should be 31 however it is ignoring the "*end_str*" and giving me all the dates till present day. The API documentation stated that "*end_str*" is optional but it should not give all the days if end date is specified. Need some help with solving this issue. The first image is the API documentation taken from Binance API  and I am running the same thing on my side in the second image.
Versions currently running:  python 3.8.0, python-binance-0.7.10 **Link to the API documentation**:
[https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/market_data.html[Binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/market_data.html%5BBinance) API documentation][1](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/market_data.html)
[image: API from Binance Website][image: Implementing same API]

Comment: Can you please insert a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to this question, of course without your api key or secret. Have you tried using `client.KLINE_INTERVAL_1DAY` (lower c for direct reference to your `Client` instance)?

Comment: @Dabhi, remember "limit" parameter: Default is 500, max is 1000.  So 30 days * 24 hours * 2 (30 minutes each) = 1440 records... it is more than max (1000).  So, try to fix it changing "end" parameter.  Divide in two or more requests.